# Pandas, Python, data missing year column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that look like this...

```
        Date      Time    Meridiem    Day
  80    01-05   9:35:00   AM      Tuesday
  81    01-05   9:40:00   AM      Tuesday
  82    01-05   9:45:00   AM      Tuesday
  83    01-05   9:50:00   AM      Tuesday
  84    01-05   9:55:00   AM      Tuesday
... ... ... ... ...
222020  11-30   3:50:00   PM      Monday
222021  11-30   3:55:00   PM      Monday
222022  11-30   4:00:00   PM      Monday
222023  11-30   4:05:00   PM      Monday
222024  11-30   4:10:00   PM      Monday
```

They are **not** datetime objects however...

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 221945 entries, 80 to 222024
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------    --------------   ----- 
 0   Date      221945 non-null  object
 1   Time      221945 non-null  object
 2   Meridiem  221945 non-null  object
 3   Day       221945 non-null  object
dtypes: object(4)
```

I need to add a column for 'Year' for this dataframe.
The data is in order and each row is in interval of 5 minutes from 9:35AM to 4:15PM (business days only), starting from 2010-01-05 to 2020-11-30 (approx. 11 years).

What would be the easiest way to add the year column? I suppose I can just manually locate the row index of last day of the year and add the year as it's only 11 items but I wanted to know if there is an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify `True` rows as the change in Year and take the cumulative sum:

1. `(df['Date'].str[0:2] == '01')` identifies January months and returns `True`
2. `(df['Date'].str[0:2] != df['Date'].shift().str[0:2]))` returns the first row of each month as `True` ensuring you only return one `True` per year, so that you can increment by one with `cumsum()` and add 2009 to get 2009 + 1 = 2010 for the first year, 2011 for the second year, etc.

---

```
df['Year'] = ((df['Date'].str[0:2] == '01') & 
              (df['Date'].str[0:2] != df['Date'].shift().str[0:2])).cumsum() + 2009
df
Out[1]: 
         Date     Time Meridiem      Day  Year
80      01-05  9:35:00       AM  Tuesday  2010
81      01-05  9:40:00       AM  Tuesday  2010
82      01-05  9:45:00       AM  Tuesday  2010
83      01-05  9:50:00       AM  Tuesday  2010
84      01-05  9:55:00       AM  Tuesday  2010
222020  11-30  3:50:00       PM   Monday  2010
222021  11-30  3:55:00       PM   Monday  2010
222022  11-30  4:00:00       PM   Monday  2010
222023  11-30  4:05:00       PM   Monday  2010
222024  11-30  4:10:00       PM   Monday  2010
80      01-05  9:35:00       AM  Tuesday  2011
81      01-05  9:40:00       AM  Tuesday  2011
82      01-05  9:45:00       AM  Tuesday  2011
83      01-05  9:50:00       AM  Tuesday  2011
84      01-05  9:55:00       AM  Tuesday  2011
222020  11-30  3:50:00       PM   Monday  2011
222021  11-30  3:55:00       PM   Monday  2011
222022  11-30  4:00:00       PM   Monday  2011
222023  11-30  4:05:00       PM   Monday  2011
222024  11-30  4:10:00       PM   Monday  2011
```